# error OpenGLRenderer: GL error: Out of memory

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have created camera application to detect user face using surface, app gets crash after 30 min and in log-cat error display as GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY.

Used Samsung S4 tab.

Can you please let me know why i am getting this issue?

Logcat Error message

```
W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.

 E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
A/OpenGLRenderer: glTexImage2D error! GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY (0x505)
```

Comment: That probably means you have some sort of memory leak somewhere in your code, inspect your code carefully to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting Out of memory error because of volley lib, I have created multiple request queue object of volley.

> You must have to create only one volley request for your application.

```
    public RequestQueue getmRequestQueue(){
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
    }
```

I have created method in application class to get only one volley request.